# Parse Nested JSON with Python and Pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to parse this json response:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "results_time": "0.6756 sec.",
    "results_count": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "date": "2017-01-01",
            "site_url": "asana.com",
            "site_title": "Use Asana to track your team’s work & manage projects · Asana",
            "site_description": "It’s free to use, simple to get started, and powerful enough to run your entire business. Sign up for free today.",
            "audience": {
                "visits": 19952871,
                "time_on_site_avg": "00:09:25",
                "page_views_avg": 6.9773123942789,
                "bounce_rate": 35.85
            },
            "traffic": {
                "value": 19952871,
                "percent": 100,
                "countries": [
                    {
                        "country": "United States",
                        "value": 6864349,
                        "percent": 34.4
                    },
                    {
                        "country": "United Kingdom",
                        "value": 1133338,
                        "percent": 5.68
                    },
                    {
                        "country": "Brazil",
                        "value": 705693,
                        "percent": 3.54
                    },
                    {
                        "country": "Canada",
                        "value": 703566,
                        "percent": 3.53
                    },
                    {
                        "country": "Poland",
                        "value": 700182,
                        "percent": 3.51
                    },
                    {
                        "country": "Other",
                        "value": 984474655,
                        "percent": 49.34
                    }
                ],
```

.........
    }

I would like to export a csv with these field:

```
audience.visits
audience.time_on_site_avg
audience.page_views_avg
audience.bounce_rate
traffic.countries.country
traffic.countries.value
traffic.countries.percent
```

I have these code but not success.

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 

with open('dict.competitor') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

traffic1 =j son_normalize(data=d['results'],record_path='traffic','countries'])

print(traffic1)
```

I feel like I am halfway there. I have tried several combinations and advice from other SO posts to get the remaining data. Nothing has worked thus far. I know the issue I am encountering is due to the nesting, just need to find a way to get the desired result. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's likely a much smarter pandas way of doing this (which would be great to see), but here is a loop that should produce the desired result.

Based on what I understand from your question this will produce a DataFrame which looks like this and can be exported to CSV:

[image]

```
data = []

for r in the_json["results"]:

    for d in r["traffic"]["countries"]:
        row = {}
        for key in d.keys():
            row["traffic.{}".format(key)] = d[key]

        for key in r["audience"]:
            row["audience.{}".format(key)] = r["audience"][key]

        data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: Which is this module the_json? I am not able to use this module.

Comment: And how to open the JSON file ? can you add the code before data[]

Comment: Could you please answer..can you please write the code before data[]

Comment: `the_json` is just a stand-in for the JSON data that the questioner supplied in their question. To open JSON files you can use the JSON file which is in the Python standard library; `import json`

Comment: I need code to handle an level of dynamic nested JSON's. The output is supposed to be in CSV format. I have pasted the same code with importing JSON, could you please help to correct it.

Comment: import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize #package for flattening json in pandas df

#load json object
with open('D:\\testjson\\test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
data = []
for r in get_json["results"]:
    for d in r["traffic"]["countries"]:
        row = {}
        for key in d.keys():
            row["traffic.{}".format(key)] = d[key]
        for key in r["audience"]:
            row["audience.{}".format(key)] = r["audience"][key]
        data.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("filename.csv")

Comment: Need you kind help!

Comment: And the results, traffic , countries are still hardcoded. How to handle DYNAMIC nested JSON's

Comment: You should probably create your own question with full examples of the code you have tried and the data structure. The answer I gave was a specific solution for the original questioner's data structure so isn't universally applicable.

Comment: The problem why I am not creating my own question is, i am blocked. The profile states, you have reached max limit of questions. So, have to post like this. Can you just copy paste the code and kindly check, I am not able to relate data[] with the opening of JSON file.